# Using Google AMP tags with Laravel Blade

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-blade, amp-html

I'm using Google AMP (moustache.js) and Laravel Blade at the same time. [According to Laravel](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/blade#blade-and-javascript-frameworks), all I have to do is add `@` before the brackets.

I can do this okay:

```
<!-- Grid-->
<amp-list width="auto"
  height="100"
  layout="fixed-height"
  src="/api/activity/all"
  [src]="acts.data"
  class="m1"
  items="data">
  <template type="amp-mustache">
    <amp-img width="108" height="70" src="@{{cover}}"></amp-img>
  </template>
</amp-list>
```

However, adding AMP List-rendered value inside the inline style doesn't work.

```
<div style="background-image:@{{cover}}; width: 100%; height: 400px; "></div>
```

BTW... it's okay now to do inline styling in AMP.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
<div style="background-image: url('@{{cover}}'); width: 100%; height: 400px; "></div>
```